# get the maximum value of the associative array in php

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [anger] => 0
    [disgust] => 20
    [fear] => 0
    [joy] => 22.853
    [sadness] => 0
    [surprise] => 0
)
Array
(
    [anger] => 0
    [disgust] => 20
    [fear] => 0
    [joy] => 22.853
    [sadness] => 0
    [surprise] => 0
)
```

I want to get key of the maximum value  from the array that is joy from the above array.
Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: Hey Niki, can you checkout the answers and clear our confusions please?

Comment: You say "the highest value", but then you're showing two arrays that are identical. How should the code handle multiple equally high values? Return both keys? First key? Last key? Or are you expecting the code to return `joy`? Should it be for the complete array or one per sub-array? The question is super unclear. Please update it with the expected output and also, add any attempt you made.

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = array_keys($yourArray,max($yourArray));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 steps given below:

Get the max value:

```
$value = max($array);
```

Get the corresponding key:

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to edit this query to get the id from the url $response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from prometric ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT echo $_GET['id']; "); to limit the data

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $array = array(
            Array
            (
                'anger' => 0,
                'disgust' => 20,
                'fear' => 0,
                'joy' => 22.853,
                'sadness' => 0,
                'surprise' => 0
            ),
            Array
            (
                'anger' => 0,
                'disgust' => 20,
                'fear' => 0,
                'joy' => 22.853,
                'sadness' => 6660,
                'surprise' => 0
            )
            );
    for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
        $maxs = array_keys($array[$i], max($array[$i]));
        print_r($maxs);
    }
    ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Array ( [0] => joy ) Array ( [0] => sadness )
```

Hope this will help you

Thanks

Muthu

Answer (score 0):

**@Niki**, above answers are appreciable. Here I've tried to present you in my way. May be, it can be similar to other answers. I will try to find other ways to do the same and update the answer.

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/MDGZ18118.

#### PHP code »

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

    $arr1 = Array
    (
        "anger" => 0,
        "disgust" => 20,
        "fear" => 0,
        "joy" => 22.853,
        "sadness" => 0,
        "surprise" => 0,
    );

    $arr2 = Array
    (
        "anger" => 0,
        "disgust" => 20,
        "fear" => 0,
        "joy" => 22.853,
        "sadness" => 0,
        "surprise" => 0,
    );

    $ret = print_r($arr1); // print_r() returns 1, if we will not store it in any variable then it will be printed on screen.
    echo "\n"; // echo "<br>"; for browser
    $ret = print_r($arr2);

    // Finding key of max element
    echo array_search(max($arr1), $arr1);
    echo("\n"); // echo "<br>"; for browser
    echo array_search(max($arr2), $arr2);
?>
```

#### Output »

```
Array
(
    [anger] => 0
    [disgust] => 20
    [fear] => 0
    [joy] => 22.853
    [sadness] => 0
    [surprise] => 0
)

Array
(
    [anger] => 0
    [disgust] => 20
    [fear] => 0
    [joy] => 22.853
    [sadness] => 0
    [surprise] => 0
)
joy
joy
```